# Failing to Load geoJSON for d3.js in Gist

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, geojson, gist

I am attempting to check whether I could correctly implement d3Vienno's code (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJgEx_yb4u0) from his d3.js Map Tutorial with geoJSON for NYC. However, my Gist is failing to properly display the map, and no errors are being thrown, as you can see here: http://bl.ocks.org/jcahan/0a25ae5f5018fc6d28c7.

I would very much appreciate any recommendations as to why this might not be working. I suppose it could be due to a lack of styling, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `transform` of SVG to translate and scale the SVG groups back to the screen. This can be further be done by using `d3.geo.bounds()`

Comment: thank you for your recommendation. I did try debugging it via the Chrome's Developer's Javascript Console. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction regarding how to do this? I am not quite sure why the svg groups aren't automatically within the scope of the page.

Comment: ref to [translate](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-translate) and [scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-scale)